# Error in Webview app

Tags: android, webview

I am very new to Java and Android programming. Just want a simple browser that enables users to visit my forum. I got this error in my java code:

```
>> Code: Webview webview; << Simple object code at the top of app. Causes: Syntax error on token "WebView", import expected.
```

Here's the full .java file code:

```
package com.droidisland.app;

WebView webview;

import android.app.Activity;

public class DroidIslandActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.loadUrl("http://droidisland.net");    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are declaring a WebView variable above your import statements and outside of the class. Move that declaration after the class declaration line, like this

```
public class DroidIslandActivity extends Activity {

    WebView webview;
```

Comment: Now i have this problem 

    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    webview cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: Post your xml file called `main.xml` located under `res/layout`

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

 <WebView
     android:id="@+id/webiew"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     
 />
 
 
</LinearLayout>

Comment: You have a typo, you declare the id as `webiew` when it should be `webview`. Also please move the xml code to your question

Answer (score 0):

```
    In your activity you can have this code:

    /*
     * entry point of the application starting the index.html of PhoneGap
     * */

    package com.capgemini.gm.myapp;

    import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;

    import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.EasyTracker;

    public class MyAppMainActivitiy extends DroidGap
    {

        String curPhoneNumber;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
            super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/app/index.html",15000); 

        }
        @Override
        public void onStart() {
         super.onStart();

         this.appView.addJavascriptInterface(new JsInterface(), "android");    
         Log.d("App start activity", "interface added");  

         curPhoneNumber = "test";

         // The rest of your onStart() code.
          EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(this); // Add this method.
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() 
        {
            super.onDestroy();

            com.google.analytics.tracking.android.EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStop(this);
        }

        public class JsInterface{       

            public String getPhoneNumber()
            {
                  return curPhoneNumber;
            }
        }
    }


and in your index.html you can have this script:

<script type="text/javascript">
     alert(android.getPhoneNumber());
</script>
```